# How to List<> of exceptions from ArgumentException and throw a AggregateException

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, aggregateexception

```
private void AccountValidations(CreateAccountPayload payload) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Note)) {
    throw new ArgumentException($ "Note cannot be empty");
  }
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.AccountName)) {
    throw new ArgumentException($ "Account Name cnnot be Empty");
  }
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Type)) {
    throw new ArgumentException($ "Account Type cnnot be Empty");
  }
}
```

I want all the exception messages at once, eg: In the payload object if I don't provide `AccountName` and `Note`. It should report me both **Note cannot be empty** and **Account Name can not be Empty** How can I do that?

I thought of making a List of all these messages and then throw a `Agregateexception`. How can I do this?

Comment: This is how you can add an exception instance to a list `list.Add( new Exception(...) );` :o)

Answer (score 2):

Well, to validate your `CreateAccountPayload` you can do the following.

A. You can indeed throw the `AggregateException` but first you need to add your exceptions to the list.

```
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Note)) {
exceptions.Add(new ArgumentException($ "Note cannot be empty"));
}
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.AccountName)) {
exceptions.Add(new ArgumentException($ "Account Name cnnot be Empty"));
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Type)) {
exceptions.Add(new ArgumentException($ "Account Type cnnot be Empty"));
}
if (exceptions.Any()) throw new AggregateException(
    "Encountered errors while validating.",
    exceptions);
```

The outer code should catch the exception.

```
catch (AggregateException e)
```

You just need to inspect the `InnerExceptions` property and construct the errors string like this

```
string.Join(" and ", e.InnerExceptions.Select(ex => ex.Message));
```

B. Another option might be the following. You can add your messages (not throwing exceptions) to a List of strings, and return it. And if the list is empty - validation passed.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have chosen to do option B, I have share code [here](https://codeshare.io/4ekO3d), but list it not empty then validation is not passed in that case can you tell me, How should I get those error messages and I am getting only one message in the list as, each one is enclosed in **if**